# How to create a JUnit of an Abstract test class with factory methods

Tags: java, junit, abstract

Sorry for asking a seemingly already answered question, but I couldn't find an answer. Sorry, if this exact case has already been answered. If yes, please point me to the thread.

```
    public abstract class AbstractBuilderTest {
    
        protected OutputBuilder builder;
    
        protected abstract OutputBuilder createBuilder(String rootName);
    
        @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
        public void testAddAboveRoot() {
            String invalidResult
                    = "<orders>"
                    + "<order>"
                    + "</order>"
                    + "</orders>"
                    + "<customer>"
                    + "</customer>";
            builder = createBuilder("orders");
            builder.addBelow("order");
            try {
                builder.addAbove("customer");
                fail("expecting java.lang.RuntimeException");
            } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
            }
        }
        
    }

public class DOMBuilderTest extends AbstractBuilderTest {
    
    @Override
    protected OutputBuilder createBuilder(String rootName) {
        return new DOMBuilder(rootName);
    }
}

public class XMLBuilderTest extends AbstractBuilderTest {

    @Override
    protected OutputBuilder createBuilder(String rootName) {
        return new XMLBuilder(rootName);
    }

}
```

With JUnit3, where you extend TestCase, this could run, with JUnit 4 however, it throws:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Comment: You are most probably attaching some JUnit annotations to your classes, which you have not shown us.  It is kind of important, you know.

Comment: import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;

Comment: Annotations are those thingies that begin with '@'.

Comment: Yes. `@Test` -->  `import org.junit.Test`; I guess you know what `@Override` means. These are all.

Comment: So, are you telling me that there are no annotations on `class AbstractBuilderTest`?

Comment: This is all the code. Create the 3 classes in your favourite IDE and run it as unit tests. You will get the error.